# Changing file name while FTP files in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I have some set of files in UNIX

```
udabpr040_mp_01 
udabpr040_mp_02
```

and so on for all 12 months, starting form 01 to 12 i.e. from udabpr040_mp_01 to udabpr040_mp_12.

Now, I want to rename the file while FTP such that only one letter shoud change and entire file remain same.i.e.

1. udabpr040_mp_01 udabtr040_mp_01
2. udabpr040_mp_02 udabtr040_mp_02

also , all the files should FTP at once. Something like

```
mput udabpr040_mp* <newfilename>
```

Does anyone knows , how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are the files on your local system or the remote FTP server?

Comment: If you're trying to rename them *as* you upload them, then you'll need to write a script to do this. Have you tried anything or are you just looking for someone to write it for you?

Comment: The files are at remote FTP server, i am very new to scripting

Answer (score 1):

this type of work called wildcard . so u must search about ftp wildcard rename as i understant your question . so i found some links . hope be useful .

http://www.networkautomation.com/automate/urc/resources/help/actions/action_FTP_Rename.htm
http://jpsoft.com/help/index.htm?ren.htm

Regards